# openstack nova api

Tags: cloud, openstack, libvirt, openstack-nova

I wand to add **Hot Memory Add/Remove feature** in OpenStack for my project.
How can i do it in openstack.also can anybody suggest me how can I call **libvirt setmem from openstack**.

Answer (score 1):

What you means is adding some new api to openstack? There are some steps you should follow, first, add apis in the project of python-xxxclient, second, if you add this api in project nova, you should add the same api in nova-api module. you can read [this blog](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/e93514d3-c4f0-4aa0-8844-497f370090f5/entry/openstack_nova_api?lang=zh).

```
grizzly/src/python-novaclient/novaclient/v1_1/shell.py
```

this file has defined all api, you can add what you need.

```
nova/api/openstack/compute/contrib
```

this directory contains most files of nova api.